# About Git GUI push Error

Tags: git, git-gui, git-lfs

I am using Windows Git GUI.When I tried to fetch the origin, it displayed a success message to me.

However when I tried to push something to origin, this error message displayed:

```
Pushing to git@<local IP>:/home/git/.git/
This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on
your path. 

If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting
.git/hooks/pre-push.

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@<local IP>:/home/git/.git/'
Error: Command Failed"
```

I cannot locate `.git/hooks/pre-push` and delete it.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use:
https://git-lfs.github.com/

And your local repository doesn't find it.

There is an open ticket for this issue:
'git-lfs' was not found on your path:
https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/853

Answer (score 1):

I did delete .git/hooks/pre-push.sample in my local repository and it worked.

I also delete the same file from the remote repository